# Mode (Statistics) on mapping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, statistics

I have a city map with digital boundaries. Each polygon has some numbers between 1 to 7. For example one of the polygon has 4,4,6,1,4,7,3,4,5,4,2 (the mode is 4 for this polygon). I wonder is there a way in Arcmap to find mode value for each polygon and make it colored by these number's value. (i.e. 1-yellow, 2- red, 3-green, etc..)?

[image: Example]

Comment: How are these numbers stored? As a single text field or as 12 numeric fields of as 12 polygons each with a single number?

Comment: Each number represents a geographic location (point) and each point has ID number. Polygons doesn't have equal numbers, some has 25, some has only 3 numbers. It stored by ID numbers on the attribute table.

Comment: I can't access the image, blocked by a web filter. Can you not post it using the StackExchange image hosting?

Comment: I too cannot view the image it just takes you to a website full of crap/adverts. Edit your question and upload the image directly into stack exchange. It is unclear what you are describing. Are you saying that for example a polygon has 25 points intersecting it and these points have ID numbers ranging from 1 to 7 and it is the mode of these you want to extract?

Comment: Let me try again w/different web site:https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GK03Thd.jpg

Comment: Please don't use a different website just use the Picture button that SE provides.

Comment: I have edited your question and inserted the image you link to. As requested do not link to images on those sites, SE can host it. It means if others come looking for the same answer they can see what you are talking about. Those picture sites can expire images uploaded to them so your link breaks.  I can answer this question but it requires re-opening.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Next time i'll make sure to do it right way.What do you mean by saying re-opening?

Comment: @Hornbydd I have reopened this question for you to add your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved with the [Spatial Join tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) and setting the appropriate field mapping merge rule.

Below is a screen shot of the tool set up as it should be to return the MODE number.

[image: Spatial Join tool]

As you can see you can return up to 11 statistics, mode being one of them.

So the logic is for each polygon, test for intersections with the join features (your points) and return the mode value and write that out to a new field (in my case called ID). The output is a copy of your polygon data with all the input fields, an intersection count and the chosen statistic (mode in this case).

Comment: No thanks required, if my answer is a solution to the problem you should tick it as such, this allows other users to know that your question got an answer which solved the problem. You tick it as solved under the vote up/down buttons.